# Change currency state from a default const object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, components, currency

I would like to change the currency prefix state from my defaultMaskOptions component, as later on this would be used as a prop in another component. This is the code:

```
const defaultMaskOptions = {
prefix: '$',
suffix: '',
includeThousandsSeparator: true,
thousandsSeparatorSymbol: '',
allowDecimal: true,
}

const CurrencyInput = ({ maskOptions, ...inputProps }) => {
const currencyMask = createNumberMask({
...defaultMaskOptions,
...maskOptions,
})

 return <MaskedInput mask={currencyMask} {...inputProps} />
}
```

Comment: It should be the way as you are passing mask to MaskedInput

Answer (score 0):

You need to make prefix state instead of a const object.

With functional components do it like this:

```
const [prefix, setPrefix] = React.useState('$')
```

Pass it into MaskedInput like this:

```
return <MaskedInput mask={currencyMask} prefix={prefix} {...inputProps} />
```

Update prefix with an onClick handler somewhere in your current component like this:

```
const handleCurrencyChange = (event) => {
   setPrefix(event.target.value)
}
```

It will re-render in the MaskedInput component when the state is updated in the parent.

**Additionaly**

If you need to update `prefix` inside MaskedInput you can pass in `setPrefix` just like any other prop and use it to update the state just like in the parent as I showed above.